# python crash course 19-1 Blog editing posts not working

Tags: python, django

I'm working on the project Blog, the `new_post` works but I can't get `edit_post` to work. In `posts.html`, if I keep the `post.id` on the link 'edit post' when I run `localhost:8000`, it shows `NoReverseMatch`; if I delete the `post.id`, I'm able to get the `edit post` tag on the homepage but when clicking on it, it shows:

> TypeError at /edit_post/

What did I do wrong? I've been going through this problem a couple days, yet can't find the solution, please help!

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    '''A blog'''
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        '''Return a string representation of the model.'''
        return self.title

    def __str__(self):
        '''Return a string representation of the model.'''    
        if len(self.text) > 50:
            return self.text[:50] + '...'
        else:
            return self.text
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import BlogPost

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'text': ''}
```

urls.py

```
'''Defines URL patterns for blogs.'''

from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'blogs'
urlpatterns = [
    # Home page
    path('', views.posts, name='posts'),

    # Page for adding a new post
    path('new_post/', views.new_post, name='new_post'),

    # Page for editing a post
    path('edit_post/', views.edit_post, name='edit_post'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import BlogPost
from .forms import PostForm

def posts(request):
    '''The home page for blog and shows all posts'''
    posts = BlogPost.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'posts': posts}
    return render(request, 'blogs/posts.html', context)

def new_post(request):
    '''Add a new post.'''
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted; create a blank form.
        form = PostForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = PostForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blogs:posts'))

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'blogs/new_post.html', context)

def edit_post(request, post_id):
    '''Edit an existing post.'''

    post = BlogPost.objects.get(id=post_id)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        # Initial request; pre-fill form with the current post.
        form = PostForm(instance=post)
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = PostForm(instance=post, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blogs:posts', args=[post.id]))

    context = {'post': post, 'posts': posts, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'blogs/edit_post.html', context)
```

posts.html

```
<p>Blog Posts</p>

<ul>
  {% for post in posts %}
    <li>{{ post }}</li>
  {% empty %}
   <li>No posts have been added yet.</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

  <a href="{% url 'blogs:new_post' %}">Add a new post:</a>

<p>
  <a href="{% url 'blogs:edit_post' post.id %}">edit post</a>
</p>

{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
```

new_post.html

```
{% extends "blogs/posts.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <p>Add a new post:</p>
  <form action="{% url 'blogs:new_post' %}" method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button name="submit">add post</button>
  </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

edit_post.html

```
{% extends "blogs/posts.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <p>Edit post:</p>

  <form action="{% url 'blogs:edit_post' post.id %}" method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button name="submit">save changes</button>
  </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are closing *forloop* before the edit_post url so you need to change here:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <li>{{ post }}</li>
  {% empty %}
   <li>No posts have been added yet.</li>

</ul>

  <a href="{% url 'blogs:new_post' %}">Add a new post:</a>

<p>
  <a href="{% url 'blogs:edit_post' post.id %}">edit post</a>
</p>
  {% endfor %}
```

And also pass the *post_id* in your url

```
path('edit_post/<int:post_id>/', views.edit_post, name='edit_post'),
```

Comment: I changed {% endfor %} and add <int:post_id>/, when I ran localhost:8000, it showed the homepage with the existing posts I added on admin page, but it didn't show the tags 'Add a new post' and 'edit post'. I tried some other ways still couldn't get the edit post to work:(

Comment: @Andy this is because of {%empty%} tag remove this tag

Comment: thank you so very much! I got the edit post tag under every single post! however when I tried to edit the post, it came out:
NoReverseMatch at /edit_post/1
and highlight view.py 'return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blogs:posts', args=[post.id]))', I tried to fix it by remove 'args=[post.id]', it still comes out the same error, but it showed the new edited post just fine when I refresh the page, how come?

Comment: @Andy because you didn't redirect to the correct path.Your post url doesn't take id so do `return redirect('blogs:posts')` only.

Comment: Wow! you're awesome!!! it works!!! ..didn't get the accept my answer part, but the code works perfectly!:)

Comment: I think I got it, sorry too new here and python, thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

In your `urls.py`, you need to add a URL pattern. [Read more here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urls/)

```py
'''Defines URL patterns for blogs.'''

from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'blogs'
urlpatterns = [
    # Home page
    path('', views.posts, name='posts'),

    # Page for adding a new post
    path('new_post/', views.new_post, name='new_post'),

    # Page for editing a post
    path('edit_post/<int:id>/', views.edit_post, name='edit_post'), 
    # Assuming 'id' is an integer, add it as a URL pattern
]
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response, I tried both <int:id>, <int:post_id>and <int:post.id>, still don't work

Comment: yes: NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'edit_post' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit_post/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$']